# How to create a Tuple object? javax.persistence.Tuple

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, interface, tuples

I understand that Tuple (javax.persistence.Tuple) is an interface. But how do I create an object with that interface? I need to build a Tuple with my custom object and a string, so (MyObject, String). Is there an existing implementation available or do I need to write a new class?

Comment: Please follow a Java tutorial on how to implement an interface in Java. If your implementation has specific technical issues then feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a basic question. Here's how I fixed this. I just created an anonymous class object. Only 1 overridden method has implementation because that is all I required.

```
Tuple myTuple = new Tuple() {

        @Override
        public <X> X get(TupleElement<X> tupleElement) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <X> X get(String s, Class<X> aClass) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object get(String s) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <X> X get(int i, Class<X> aClass) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object get(int i) {
            Map<Integer, Object> tuple = new HashMap<>();
            tuple.put(0, myObject);
            tuple.put(1, myId);
            return tuple.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] toArray() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        @Override
        public List<TupleElement<?>> getElements() {
            return null;
        }
    };
```